# Is countable infinity part of the natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, infinity

A hopefully relatively simple question: is *countable* infinity an element of the set of natural numbers? A [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354474/is-infinity-an-element-of-the-natural-numbers) here has been answered with the statement that (classic) infinity is not part of the natural numbers, but what about countable infinity?

---

**Context for this question**: A definition of a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) I have come across is as follows:

*The reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS) $\mathcal{H}$ is the closure of the linear span $\{f:f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_ik(x,x_i), \space a_i \in \mathbb{R}, \space m \in \mathbb{N}, x_i \in \mathcal{X}\}$ equipped with inner products $\left< f,g \right>_{\mathcal{H}}=\sum_{ij}a_ib_jk(x_i,x_j)$ for $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} b_ik(x,x_i)$.*

Many examples or RKHSs have infinitely many dimensions, so we would require $m=\infty \in \mathbb{N}$. Feel free to ignore this context if it is not required for your answer.

Comment: No, The set of [naturals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) is $\mathbb N = \{ 0,1,2,\ldots \}$

Comment: A subset of that set, actually.

Comment: Your context is of interest here.  Although we can only sum a finite number of vectors, when a vector space has a topology it can be asked if an "infinite sum" has a well-defined limit of its partial sums.  But no, countable infinity is not a natural number.

Comment: @hardmath: So in this case, closure is interpreted as topological closure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology) )? I haven't studied math, so the different definitions of closure in mathematics keep confusing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not need $m = \infty$. Note that you are taking the closure of the linear span, which takes care of the elements requiring an infinite sum for their representation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If you could elaborate: why does the closure of the linear span do this? I struggle to find definitions for what "closure of a linear span" means.

Comment: @J.Galt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)